# Issue facing with storybook for React Please guide me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

i am new to React and facing this issue with storybook please help.

```
import React from 'react'
import Suc  from '../Input/Input'
import Success from '../Button/Button'


export default {
    title: "Form/Form",
    component: Success


};

export const SuccessForm = () => {
    <>
    <Suc />
    <Success />
    </> 
}
```

unboundStoryFn(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

screenshot Attached.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H6gP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIJTO.png

Comment: Share your code !

Comment: Maybe the `Suc` or `Success` components don't have a render function?

Comment: Can you share the code of the two components? `Suc` and `Success `

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that story file. The problem must be in either `../Input/Input` or `../Button/Button`. Most likely a missing `return` statement, as React suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const SuccessForm = () => {
    <>
    <Suc />
    <Success />
    </> 
}
```

should be

```js
export const SuccessForm = () => {
    return(
        <>
        <Suc />
        <Success />
        </> 
    )
}
```

let me know if it fixed.